# How to set order in init scripts?

Tags: scripting, centos, init, upstart

I create some /etc/init scripts, but one script (script B) depend on other (script A). How to order execution of those scripts? I want to system first execute script A, and then script B. Process that start script B will be killed and execute again couple of times during one day, and I want to script A execute only on reboot not every time before script B. How to do that?

Comment: Call one from the other instead of putting them both in the script folder?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

1. Put `script A` outside `/etc/init` and make a call to it in the very beginning of `script B`.
2. Put `script B` outside `/etc/init` and make a call to it in the very end of `script A`

**EDIT**

If the calling sequence is always `A; B` for `B`, but `A` runs independently only on reboot, you have another option:

3. Put `script B` outside `/etc/init` since it does not belong there and call `/etc/init/A` from the beginning of it.

Comment: Yes that would solve the problem, but i didn't describe my problem well. Process that start script B will be killed and execute again couple of times during one day, and I want to script A execute only on reboot not every time  before script B.

Comment: #1, add that to your question, #2, I will update my answer.